# Flutter: Row with flexible and spacer not working

Tags: flutter, flexbox, alignment, row, spacing

I am building a widget to look like Tweets. At the moment, the header is the following row:

```
Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
          Flexible(
            flex: 3,
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
              child: Text(
                poster.name,
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .headline4!
                    .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 14,
            child: Text(
              '${poster.handle} · ${timeago.format(wave.createdAt)}',
              style:
                  Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5!.copyWith(fontSize: 12),
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            ),
          ),
          Spacer(),
          if (showPopup)
            WaveTilePopup(
                poster: poster, wave: wave, user: user, onDeleted: onDeleted),
        ],
      ),
```

Which look like this:
[image]

When i increase the flex property of the name text, it will fix the formatting on the name, however shorter names will result in the PopUp being away from the right alignment, which is where I want it to be in a consistent manner:

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: share your expected design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of all hard-coded `flex`, you can just wrap your more button with `expanded` and `align` widget like this:

```
Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    children: [
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5.0),
        child: Text(
          poster.name,
          style: Theme.of(context)
              .textTheme
              .headline4!
              .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14),
        ),
      ),
      Text(
        '${poster.handle} · ${timeago.format(wave.createdAt)}',
        style: Theme.of(context)
            .textTheme
            .headline5!
            .copyWith(fontSize: 12),
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          child: showPopup
              ? WaveTilePopup(
                  poster: poster,
                  wave: wave,
                  user: user,
                  onDeleted: onDeleted)
              : SizedBox(),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

[image]